# Can I play Borderlands 2 GOTY with a vanilla disc after installing DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

**tl;dr:** Playing Borderlands 2 GOTY DLC with a Borderlands 2 (vanilla) disc seems to work ok. Can anyone confirm?

I have a copy of the Borderlands 2 GOTY Edition as well as a Borderlands 2 (vanilla) disc. I installed the GOTY DLC and played for a few hours, then I realized I had put the Borderlands 2 (vanilla) disk into the Xbox 360 *after* installing the GOTY DLC and not the GOTY disc 1.

Is the GOTY disc 1 the same as the vanilla disc?

Can anyone else confirm this behavior? Are there problems later on in the game?

Comment: I don't have those exact discs, as I bought all the DLC online, but there's no reason to think that wouldn't work. Did the GOTY version come with a separate disc containing all the DLC?

Comment: The GOTY version came with 2 discs. 1. The main game. 2. The DLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The GOTY disc is the same as the vanilla disc, but also includes the DLC. Once the DLC has been activated on your account and installed on your console, you can use the vanilla disc or the GOTY disc interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm this will work from experimentation with those *exact* discs, but I can be pretty confident that everything should be fine.

Given that the DLC is designed to work with the base game, it would be extremely strange for a different version of the base game to be shipped with the DLC.

I've had plenty of other games that came in a 2-disc set with DLC on the second disc, and those were all completely compatible with the original disc.

If they weren't compatible, it's doubtful that the game would have launched at all.

Comment: This smells like trouble for the used games market.

Comment: @SamuelRenkert You've been able to install DLC from your friend's DLC disc, give it back, and continue playing on your own game disc for many years. We did that back with Oblivion on the original Xbox.